2 queries with the same return type but Apollo types them differently
I have 2 queries from a graphql scheme
ProductApp(countrycode: String!, languagecode: String!, productType: String!): [Product]
ProductDetails(fundid: String!, countrycode: String!, languagecode: String!): Product

When I generate the files using CLI generate, perform the calls and use the documented code to get the result
if let products = try? result.get().data?.productApp

The resulting object is productApp, and from the details call it is productDetails, but in the schema they are both of type Product, is there a way for me to get the respective Product/[Product] types from the data?
